# is it possible to automate device enrollment process using Intune MDM?

Tags: ios, mdm

We are trying to give our staff an enterprise app using Intune MDM. Here are the steps we followed: https://www.robinhobo.com/how-to-enroll-an-apple-device-with-ios-13-user-enrollment-mode-in-microsoft-intune/

We have a requirement that we need to automate the Enrollment of iOS device so that end-users do not need to do all the steps like they will select the app and then install so from a mobile we have to do the remaining steps automatically.

Can we automate the steps below?

- download management profile
- install the management profile
- update device settings

Comment: And you have contacted Intune MDM support and they said what exactly that was not helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple can compel device enrollment automation that triggers no touch download and forced enrollment.

- http://deploy.apple.com/

iOS devices require user approved enrollment unless the hardware was purchased under a business account. This subset of hardware can be automatically managed devices as part of an enterprise or business account. Your three steps would work for these iOS devices.

Since your three steps are three different processes, focus on them sequentially.

Figure how to update settings once a device is managed (by Intune in your case) as you likely have the most control over that initially.

Then you will have two paths for the other two steps. User assisted enrollment of a device and Apple DEP process that points to your specific MDM.

- https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/DEP_Guide.pdf
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/welcome/web

Read this PDF and site for some great tips, like manual supervision via Apple Configurator.